# Powershell Script - Upload Appointments to Outlook Group Calendar

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm currently working at a Powershell script to pull data from a CSV of a couple thousand appointments that need to be migrated to an Outlook group calendar. As of now, I've been able to parse the data into Outlook events and successfully upload to my personal calendar.

However, I've been unsuccessful uploading to a **group** calendar. Any suggestions on how I can modify the folder path in my code (see below), to change the save destination from my personal default calendar to a group Calendar which I am the owner of? (E.g. I have a group called "Test-Group" which I am using to test this, it is a calendar I can select and post to in Outlook). Also, I need the O365 group itself to be the owner of the events.

```
    #Currently handles subject, start date, end date, duration, all day event, body, required attendees, location (room)

    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook'

    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application            
    $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')          
    $Calendar = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderCalendar

    # vv folder path for the calendar we are uploading to
    $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($Calendar)

    $ImportFile ="C:\Users\evanv\Downloads\Appointment-Outlook-Test.csv"
    $calendar = $outlook.Session.GetFolderFromID($folder.EntryID, $folder.StoreID)
    $csv = Import-CSV $ImportFile           

    foreach($row in $csv) 
    {       
       $appt = $calendar.Items.Add(1)
       $appt.Subject = $row.Subject
       $appt.Start = $row.StartDate
       #$appt.End = $row.EndDate
       $appt.Duration = $row.Duration
       $appt.AllDayEvent = $false
       $appt.Body = $row.ApptID
       #$appt.Organizer = $row.Clinic  --read only property :(
       $appt.RequiredAttendees = $row.Attendees
       $appt.Location = $row.Room   
       $appt.Body = $row.Location_Street + "\n" + $row.ApptID

       Write-Host "Row " $row.Subject " added to calendar" -ForegroundColor green           
       $appt.Save()             
    }
```

For the record, I have scoured Google and been unsuccessful thus far in finding anything that fits my needs; an actual solution here would be a welcome surprise.. That said, any other ideas for how to get these events to my group calendar would also be gratefully welcomed!

Comment: Instead of using Office Interop I'd suggest you use EWS (Exchange Web Services) or MS Graph for this. It!s must faster, easier and reliable to use. Glen Scales has an excellent blog with a lot of code samples on how to work with calendar item's using either of these API's

Comment: Ditto with what 'bluuf 'is saying here, but in order to do many use cases in EXP/EXO (Exchange on-prem/Exchange Online) you must be granted the appropriate Exchange Admin rights and privileges to do so. Such as Excahgne Org Admin, App Impersonation, etc. In many cases, Exchange admins and risk management policies prevent such rights and privileges from being allowed without specific/validated/auditable reasons.